# Loop through projects in Solution Folder and get properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

**Summary:**

Is it possible to loop through each project in a certain Solution Folder and get properties from a class or interface each project has? And if so can I require each project to contain this certain class?

**Explanation:**

I've got a ASP.NET Web API project.

A part of this project is the API Framework for example:

- Authentication
- Logging
- Help page generation

This part probaply won't change much over time and if it changes it are probaply breaking changes or changes that don't influence the Api interface at all.

The other part is the API endpoints for example:

- Users
- Relations
- Reactions
- Likes

This part will change relatively often and so I would like to implement versioning.
My idea is to make each new version in a new project for example:

- Api.Endpoints.V1
- Api.Endpoints.V2
- Api.Endpoints.V3

I would like this projects to all have an Interface which I can call in the main Api project to add a new version.

For example I would like all `Api.Endpoints.V*` projects to expose a (Odata) `IEdmModel` property which I can loop through and register in my Main project. In code this would look something like:

**Api.Endpoints.V1:**

```
namespace Api.Endpoints.V1
{
    public class DataModel
    {
        public Model IEdmModel { get; private set; }

        public DataModel()
        {
            ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            modelBuilder.EntitySet<Users>("Users");
            modelBuilder.EntitySet<Relations>("Relations");
            modelBuilder.EntitySet<Reactions>("Reactions");
            modelBuilder.EntitySet<Likes>("Likes");
            this.IEdmModel = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Api project (pseudo code):**

```
namespace Api
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
       foreach(project in VersionsFolder)
       {
           configuration.Routes.MapODataRoute(routeName: project.Version, routePrefix: project.Version, model: project.Model);
       }    
    }
}
```

Is it possible to make these Endpoint projects confirm to a certain interface, for example always contain a class `DataModel` which implements a certain Interface and loop through this in the Register Method in the Main project? Or am I going wrong here and should I solve this in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some tools for keeping different versions, for example simple one is [svn](http://subversion.apache.org/), also you can use [github](https://github.com/) online, it's not good to keep different version in one solution and you should handle versionning automatically. Also I prefer to use TFS for keeping branches and different releases.

Comment: I downvoted, versioning is off vital importance when building an api. You are talking about version control which is a different form of versioning. When the API interface changes I want to release a new version and leave the old one as it is so I don't break existing clients. I think that every well designed Api is versioned. For example: api.instagram.com/v1/ also see: http://apigee.com/docs/enterprise/content/when-version-your-api

Comment: @JosVinke, In any good versioning tool you can also save subversions, you can make new branch, and every time you want you can get the specific version automatically, for example you can use team fundation server if you want nice branching. e.g see this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/177383/in-tfs-how-should-different-releases-be-structured-version-1-0-version-2-0

Comment: I am using Team Foundation Server, I know how to make branches, create labels etc. I don't see how this solves my problem? I want to run separate versions at the same time. When for example the class user gets a new property I don't want to change V1, cause it could break a client. I want to create V2 and add the property there. V1 should be unchanged and they should both be available. So api/v1/user and api/v2/user should both be available as long as possible. So clients can update their code and once less clients use v1, or after some period off time we can remove support for V1.

Comment: @JosVinke Right, I hear you, but what's wrong with relying on version control? You'll get a LOT of projects/classes this way. And what does it really add besides complexity? If you want to make changes for an existing customer release for a specific version, you apply the change on the matching branch.

Comment: @JosVinke, Actually I didn't see any software that runs on different versions in same time, as you can see every api extends previous versions functionality, and you shouldn't have different version running in one application.

Comment: I think I must apologize I was to single minded on this solution. I think I understand what you are trying to tell me. Should I just add a new application once I've got a new Version in IIS? And then save a branch in TFS and go on from that point on?

Comment: Nah, you can still look at it. And if that customer requires changes, you apply the change on that particular branch. When that customer wants the latest &greatest software you built, you release the software from you main line.

Comment: My idea about versioning came from using this https://nuget.org/packages/SDammann.WebApi.Versioning package. But if I understand it well this is totally wrong? This is going to be a pretty quick eye opener.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri thanks for your help it is greatly appriciated I upvoted your answer and marked it as answer. My apologies for being so single minded on the solution.

Comment: @JosVinke, take it easy man, it was good that you wrote your downvote reason and we had good discussion.